# Output hello in vaadin chat dialog (Spring boot and spring scheduler + vaadin 14)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin, scheduler

I created a chat on the vaadine and spring boot. So I have a problem with the scheduler, I wanted to write a scheduler that displays "hello" every second, but how can I write so that it calls hello every second, only it was like this
Example output -

```
hello 1 - (when 1 second has passed)
hello 2 - (after two seconds)
hello 3 - (after three seconds)
.
.
.
.
hello 45 - (after 45 seconds)
.
.
.
.
hello 100 - (after 100 seconds)
```

Image example
[image]

My code, How can I launch a sсheduler in a chat when I log in

```
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    private final MessagesInfoManager messagesInfoManager;
    private final RestService restService;
    private String username;



     private int count=0;

    @Autowired
    public MainView(RestService restService) {
        this.messagesInfoManager = MessageConfigurator.getInstance().getChatMessagesInfoManager();
        addClassName("main-view");
        setSizeFull();
        setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER);

        H1 header = new H1("Vaadin Chat");
        header.getElement().getThemeList().add("dark");

        add(header);

        askUsername();
        this.restService = restService;
    }

    private void askUsername() {
        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        TextField usernameField = new TextField();
        Button startButton = new Button("Start chat");

        layout.add(usernameField, startButton);

        startButton.addClickListener(click -> {
            username = usernameField.getValue();
            remove(layout);
            showChat(username);
        });

        add(layout);
    }

    private void showChat(String username) {
        MessageList messageList = new MessageList();

        List<Message> lasts = restService.getLast();
        for (Message message : lasts) {
            messageList.add(new Paragraph(message.getFrom() + ": " + message.getMessage()));
        }

        add(messageList, createInputLayout(username, messageList));
        expand(messageList);
    }

    private Component createInputLayout(String username, MessageList messageList) {
        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        layout.setWidth("100%");

        TextField messageField = new TextField();
        messageField.addKeyDownListener(Key.ENTER, keyDownEvent -> sender(messageField, messageList));
        Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
        sendButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);

        layout.add(messageField, sendButton);
        layout.expand(messageField);

        messageField.addFocusListener(event -> {
            for (Message message : messagesInfoManager.getMessagesByUI(getUI())) {
                if (!message.getFrom().equals(username)) {
                    message.setUnread(false);
                    this.restService.updateMessage(message.getId(), message);
                }
            }
        });

        sendButton.addClickListener(click -> sender(messageField, messageList));
        messageField.focus();

        return layout;
    }

    private void sender(TextField textField, MessageList messageList) {
        Message message = new Message(username, textField.getValue());
        message = restService.saveMessage(message);
        messagesInfoManager.updateMessageUIInfo(new MessageInfo(messageList, message, this));
        textField.clear();
        textField.focus();
    }






@Scheduled (fixedDelay = 1000)
public void test() {
    count++; 
    System.out.println("Hello"+count);

}
}
```

In the compiler displays, now i need to chat
[image]

Comment: This is the third question that is virtually the same as the previous ones? Why don't you add your progress to the existing questions and refine them by that?

Answer (score 0):

How you put up a scheduler in Java is not much related to Vaadin in itself. You can use a second thread that you run, or as you seem to have, a readymade tool for it. Looks like a Spring feature if I'm not mistaken.

After that, you update the Vaadin components to contain the new messages. You can for example make your messageList into a field and within `test()` add a new paragraph to it. Or use the backend service that you have to push messages in from there.

When you do update the UI from a secondary thread, remember that you might run into race conditions. For that reason, you should [lock the user session for the time that you make UI changes](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-access.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
    public void test() {
        count++;
        System.out.println("Hello" + count);

        this.getUI().get().access(() -> {

            if (messageList != null) {
                messageList.add(new Paragraph("From me" + ": " + "Hello" + count));
            }

        });

    }
}
```

Comment: If this is an answer, could you please add some explanatory text?